# Define index in $_SESSION with .(dot) concatenation 

Tags: php, session, post, indexing

I'm getting a PHP Notice if I set a $_SESSION index without submission.
Wanted to know if there is a workaround?

The Notice:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  bar

PHP

```
if($validation_condition) {
    $_SESSION['bar'] = 'foo';
}
```

The validation process stops the form from submitting, saves the form data to a database and reloads the page. The $_SESSION['bar'] displays the correct value but I get a Notice in the logs. Wanting to stop the Notice.

Here is the var_dump()

```
array(1) {
  ["bar"]=>
  string(3) "foo"
}
```

as you can see it's getting set.

There is one small difference from my original question, I'm setting it like this

```
$_SESSION['bar'] .= 'foo';
```

With the .(dot) concatenation. When I removed it the Notice went away.

SLAP HEAD ON DESK!

Comment: umm... is it as silly question as it seems at first?

Comment: I agree @Col.Shrapnel to me it should not matter when I set the session and the session is getting set properly but why am I getting a Notice?

Comment: @Phill Pafford: The notice should have an accompanying line number. Can you show the code (and surrounding code) the line number is referring to? The PHP code you show (`$_SESSION['bar'] = 'foo';`) is not causing the notice.

Comment: Yes the line number point to where I'm setting the $_SESSION['bar'] and on page reload I can see the session that I set. The session is displaying the correct value but in the logs I get a PHP Notice and I wanted to know why. BTW It's example code

Comment: "the line number point to where I'm setting the $_SESSION['bar']" Simple assignment will never cause a notice about the left-hand side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

one approach is to ensure that `$_SESSION['bar']` is set under both conditions:

```
if ($validation_condition) {
    $_SESSION['bar'] = 'foo';
} else {
    $_SESSION['bar'] = '';
}
```

Alternatively, in your display code, you can first check for the existence of `$_SESSION['bar']`:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['bar'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['bar'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$_SESSION['bar'] = $validation_condition ? 'foo' : '';
```

Answer (score 1):

The notice simply sais that the array `$_SESSION` doesn't have an index called `'bar'`. If you're not sure whether the index exists, you should check it:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['bar']))
  echo $_SESSION['bar'];
else
  echo 'something else';
```

Comment: I understand that but the value I set for bar in the session display correctly. The problem is I get the PHP Notice in my logs and I want to know how to get rid of it

Comment: If you call `var_dump($_SESSION)`, do you see the `bar` index?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what was asked in this vague question, but here is my bet

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if($validation_condition) {
        $_SESSION['bar'] = 'foo';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should only get this notice when you're trying to read `$_SESSION['bar']` and it doesn't exist, not while trying to set it.  Make sure any code that reads the value checks that it exists first.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that your PHP file is trying to get the session.

First of all, declare in every place you will use a session, the following:

```
session_start();
```

Then, according to what you show in your post, you can do this in your PHP file:

```
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['bar']){
   if ($validation_condition) {
       $_SESSION['bar'] = 'foo';
   } else {
      $_SESSION['bar'] = '';
   }
} else {
    $_SESSION['bar'] = '';
}
```

This is just an idea but someday I got the same error as you and 'isset' solve my problem.